# SQL Join with operator IN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm having a problem joining two tables using `IN`. 
Example:

```
with nodes(node_id, mpath) as (
 SELECT node_id, drugs_cls_node_view.mpath
 FROM drugs_cls_entries_view
   inner join drugs_cls_node_view on drugs_cls_node_view.id = node_id
 WHERE mnn_id in (13575)
)
select DISTINCT n.node_id, drugs_cls_node_view.*  
from nodes n
  inner join drugs_cls_node_view
  on drugs_cls_node_view.id in (array_replace(string_to_array(n.mpath, '/'), '', '0')::bigint[])
```

I get the exception:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]

Comment: The answer is yes, you can join two tables using IN.

Comment: @jarlh but i got exception: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]`

Comment: Please [simplify your query to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will make it clearer both to us and to you where the problem lies.

Comment: what's the data in `n.mpath` ?

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ `VARCHAR`

Comment: @Wolkodav I meant the content, show it

Comment: try this `drugs_cls_node_view.id= any( (array_replace(string_to_array(n.mpath, '/'), '', '0')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
on drugs_cls_node_view.id in 
  (array_replace(string_to_array(n.mpath, '/'), '', '0')::bigint[])
```

you look for the ID in a set containing just one element. This element is an array. The ID can never equal the array, hence the error.

You must unnest the array to have single values to compare with:

```
on drugs_cls_node_view.id in 
  (select(unnest(array_replace(string_to_array(n.mpath, '/'), '', '0')::bigint[])))
```

Or use ANY on the array instead of IN:

```
on drugs_cls_node_view.id = ANY
  (array_replace(string_to_array(n.mpath, '/'), '', '0')::bigint[])
```

There may be syntactical errors in my code, as I am no postgres guy, but it should do with maybe a little correction here or there :-)

Comment: Why `ANY` is slower with `LIKE` in this query?

Comment: I don't understand this question, but not being a postgres person, it isn't likely I could answer it anyhow :-) Arrays and `= ANY` are special PostgreSQL features.